# Adding Workflow to few Documents in a Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, document-library

In SharePoint it is known that a workflow can be added to the document library.  Is there a way to create a SharePoint Designer workflow to apply to one or two documents in the library not the whole library? Is it best to use a SharePoint Designer workflow or out of the box workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the workflow on item creation or modification bur executing the actual workflow logic (action) write an if condition like - if filename equals (or some other criteria) "This file" then perform your rest of the action, this way we can execute workflow action based on the attributes. However, if you have a third party product like Nintex - you can even trigger the workflow conditionally, on the specific item.